# wp-admin - 404 after custom login form

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login, wp-login-form

I create custom login form in my page with this code:

```
add_filter('login_redirect', 'my_login_redirect', 10, 3);
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $requested_redirect_to, $user) {
    if (is_wp_error($user)) {
        //Login failed, find out why...
        $error_types = array_keys($user->errors);
        //Error type seems to be empty if none of the fields are filled out
        $error_type = 'both_empty';
        //Otherwise just get the first error (as far as I know there
        //will only ever be one)
        if (is_array($error_types) && !empty($error_types)) {
            $error_type = $error_types[0];
        }
        wp_redirect( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "?login=failed&reason=" . $error_type ); 
        exit;
    } else {
        //Login OK - redirect to another page?
        $red_url = get_bloginfo( 'url' ) . '/zona-novinky/';
        return $red_url;
    }
}
```

But problem is, my /wp-admin or wp-login page doesn't work now.
It gives me this error: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

How can I use wp-admin / wp-login and custom login form in my page (with error messeges) in same time?